# Solve for not y = 0 but for y = n

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, functions, homework

Let’s see if I manage to explain this well enough. I need to find roots of an equation(let’s say a quartic) but not at the points where the slope crosses the $x$-axis (y = 0), like the `Solve` function does by default, I need roots of `y = 2`, for example.

This should be so simple I think yet I’m not sure how to do that.

---

[image: roots]

This is what I’m trying to achieve using Mathematica. Find the points where the slope crosses E=1 etc.

Comment: `Solve[{2 y - y^2 == 0, y != 0}, y]`?

Comment: The question is not clearly stated. Do you want to filter roots of the equations by some constraints or to change the equation?

Comment: Let me try add a picture, might make this easier :)

Comment: Wow, this website is moderated at the speed of light haha, impressive.

Comment: From a mathematical perspective, if you have a function f(x), you can translate it vertically by adding or subtracting. So f(x) - 3 would put anything that used to be on the line y = 3 at y = 0. To avoid tranlating, we just add 3 to both sides of f(x) - 3 = 0 to get f(x) = 3. That’s why `Solve[f(x) ==3, x]` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your function is

```
f[x_] := x^3 + x^2 + 2 x + 3
```

Then you can use solve to find the roots

```
Solve[f[x] == 0, x]
```

To find where it crosses (say) 3, use

```
Solve[f[x] == 3, x]
```

Comment: That was my guess actually and I tried to enter that in wolframalpha, then thought this might be too simple to work. Feel stupid now...